# Django: how to work around "Keyword can't be an expression" error

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

In the code below, `capitals_listings_from_latest_Celery_scrape` is a QuerySet of `Listing` model objects:

```
capitals_listings_from_latest_Celery_scrape = capitals_listings_all.filter(date_added.date()=latest_Celery_scrape_date)
```

However, I currently get

> "Keyword can't be an expression"

error on this line, because of `date_added.date()` part.

The reason I am using `.date()` is that in order to properly evaluate `date_added` against `latest_Celery_scrape_date` I need to strip `date_added` from time data and leave only the year, month and day.

How do I fix the error?

Comment: The `date_added.date()=latest_Celery_scrape_date` is wrong syntax, you can not perform a function call as parameter identifier.

Comment: You probably want `date_added__date=latest_Celery_scrape_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you make a call as keyword (the parameter name), whereas a parameter name should be an identifier:

```
capitals_listings_from_latest_Celery_scrape = capitals_listings_all.filter(
    date_added.date()=latest_Celery_scrape_date
)
```

If you use such syntax, you indeed get this error, for example:

```
>>> id(id()=3)
  File "", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Django however has a lookup for this: the [**`__date`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#date) lookup. So you can query like:

```
capitals_listings_from_latest_Celery_scrape = capitals_listings_all.filter(
    date_added__date=latest_Celery_scrape_date
)
```

Note however that the `date` of a timestamp is in itself a complicated problem, since one can aim to find the date within that specific time zone, or the data of that timestamp in the *current* timezone.

As specified in the documentation for the `__date` lookup:

> When `USE_TZ` is `True`, fields are **converted to the current time zone** before filtering.